# animate li tags when clicked in css

Tags: css

tell me why the code does not work, I hachu with the click to animate the li tags, the animation goes one after another, for 3 seconds

```css
#menu #sm-menu:checked~.menu2 li {
  animation: menu 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes menu {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }
}

#menu .menu2 ul li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

#menu .menu2 ul li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}

#menu .menu2 ul li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: .9s;
}

#menu .menu2 ul li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
```

```html
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
    <a href=""><i>fas</i></a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sm-menu">
    <div class="sm-menu"><label for="sm-menu"><i>fa</i>fas</label></div>
    <nav class="menu2">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu3</a>
         <ul>
           <li>1</li>
           <li>2</li>
           <li>3</li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: @HovikGhambaryan You can always edit your question to add additional information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in [*CSS specificity*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).
This rule's selector

```
#menu #sm-menu:checked~.menu2 li {
  animation: menu 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

is **stronger** than this

```
#menu .menu2 ul li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}
```

so it **overrides** it, and using the shorthand `animation` property overrides `animation-delay` in the following rules.

You have two solutions:
 - The better one: make the rules below stronger like this (a refined version of your CSS):

```
#sm-menu:checked~.menu2 li {
  animation: menu 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes menu {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }
}

#menu .menu2 li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

#menu .menu2 ul li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}

#menu .menu2 ul li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: .9s;
}

#menu .menu2 ul li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
```

- The second rough one is to use the `!important` rule which is an exception that overrides any other selector like this.

Note: It's always best to use as succinct selectors as you can.

Comment: here you have not changed anything everything works as before, that is, it does not work

Comment: @HovikGhambaryan Glad it worked. If you're satisfied with the answer, please accept it. It's usually a good practice, so people having the same problem as yours get the right answer directly.